# How to get different info-plist from iOS unit test?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest, info.plist

In my iOS app, I have a library (that I cannot edit) that grabs something from the app's info-plist file. The library uses this code to get the plist:

```
infoDict = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] infoDictionary];
```

In the app, it works great. But when I run a unit test that uses the same method, the line above returns the info-plist of the Tests bundle instead of the main one. What can I do in my unit test to get around this, since I can't change the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSBundle mainBundle], this will return your app bundle

Comment: I may have understood incorrectly, but are you suggesting that @user1007895 should edit the `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]` with `[NSBundle mainBundle]`? If that's so, he said that he can't edit it.